# Escape hatch for husky v6?

Tags: husky, git-husky

I've recently installed [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) v6 - and I love it. But sometimes I would like to avoid running it - is there some argument that provides an escape hatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Git offers a `--no-verify` option for the `pre-commit` hook:

> This hook is invoked by git-commit[1], and can be bypassed with the --no-verify option. It takes no parameters, and is invoked before obtaining the proposed commit log message and making a commit.

Making the git commit with this flag enabled disables husky.